# Почему NEXT_DAY работает иначе в PL/SQL чем в SQL? ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Этот SQL запрос работает:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY (sysdate, 7) "NEXT DAY" FROM DUAL;
  
NEXT DAY
-------------------
2021-08-15 00:31:12
```

Но в PL/SQL эта же функция не работает:

```
declare
    nextday date := NEXT_DAY (sysdate, 7);
begin null;
end;
/
```

> ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week

Не хотелось бы жестко кодировать дни недели во втором параметре на английском, например:

```
NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'SATURDAY') 
--или 
NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'SUNDAY')
```

Пока использую следующее решение:

```
dteExpires DATE := NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2021-08-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'DAY'));
```

Хотелось бы узнать, почему `NEXT_DAY()` ведет себя иначе в PL/SQL, чем в SQL?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [NEXT_DAY function works differently in SQL vs. PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43104695) от участника [@wweicker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8432/wweicker)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/43104695

Answer (score 4):

Если посмотрeть документацию к [SQL функции NEXT_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/NEXT_DAY.html#GUID-01B2CC7A-1A64-4A74-918E-26158C9096F6), то можно заметить, что передача числа для представления дня недели не документирована. По какой-то причине она работает, но если положиться на это, то есть риск, что в будущем Oracle изменит реализацию, чтобы она соответствовала спецификации этой функции (риск невелик, но всё таки).

Реализация PL/SQL работает только с документированной спецификацией - она не принимает числовой параметр для представления дня недели.

Учитывая документацию, вопрос лучше поставить так: *Почему это работает в SQL?*.
Только разработчики Oracle могут ответить на этот вопрос.

Возможно [это обсуждение на OTN](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4023654) будет полезно, или [это тоже](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/17257?tab=comment).

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43105338/6571020) от участника [@mathguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5683823/mathguy)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Считаю, что единственный способ сделать функцию `NEXT_DAY` независимой от текущих NLS параметров сессии БД, это обходной путь с ISO-неделей, где первый день недели всегда понедельник. То есть, добавив 1 - будет вторник, 2 - среда и т.д.:

```
declare
    nextday date := next_day (sysdate, to_char (trunc (sysdate, 'IW')+4, 'DAY'));
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('next day='||nextday); 
end;
/
```

> next day=2021-08-13 01:25:54

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43109487) от участника [@Wernfried Domscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027266/wernfried-domscheit)</sub>